# How to prevent BottomSheetDialogFragment from dismissing after a navigation to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-navigation, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am using `NavigationComponent` on my App.

I have an specific flow where after a click on a button of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` the app should navigate to another fragment. But when that Fragment is popped I need to navigate back to the previous `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

For some reason the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is being dismissed automatically.

```
Frag A : click on a button  
Frag A -> Dialog B : click on a button  
Frag A -> Dialog B -> Frag C : pop Frag C from the stack  
Frag A : Dialog B was automatically dismissed =;/
```

How can one prevent that dismissing?

---

Q: Why do I need the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` not dismissed?
A: I listen to the result of the opened fragment through a `LiveData`. Due to the dismissing of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` it never receives the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible. Dialog destinations implement the [FloatingWindow interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/FloatingWindow) which states:

> Destinations that implement this interface will automatically be popped off the back stack when you navigate to a new destination.

So it is expected that dialog destinations are automatically popped off the back stack when you navigate to a `<fragment>` destination. This is *not* the case when navigating between multiple dialog destinations (those can be stacked on top of one another).

[This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/134089818) explains a bit more about the limitations here, namely that:

> 1. Dialogs are separate windows that always sit above your activity's window. This means that the dialog will continue to intercept the system back button no matter what state the underlying FragmentManager is in or what FragmentTransactions you do.
> 2. Operations on the fragment container (i.e., your normal  destinations) don't affect dialog fragments. Same if you do FragmentTransactions on a nested FragmentManager.

So once you navigate to your `<fragment>` destination, the only way for the system back button to actually work is for all floating windows to be popped (otherwise they would intercept the back button before anything else) as those windows are always floating above the content.

This isn't a limitation imposed by the Navigation Component - the same issues apply to any usages of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` regarding the Fragment back stack and the system back button.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation \o/. I'll try a workaround for that situation ^^

Comment: How does one go around this then? @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as pointed out by @ianhanniballake.

But this can be achieved by making `fragment C` as a `DailogFragment`, not a normal `Fragment`, but this requires some effort to make it behave like a normal fragment.

In this case both `B` & `C` are dialogs and therefore they'll share the same back stack. and hence when the back stack is poped up to back from `C` to `B`, you'll still see the BottomSheetDialgFragment `B` showing.

To fix the limited window of `C` use the below theme:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Where `Theme.MyApp` is your app's theme.

And then apply it to `C` by overriding `getTheme()`:

```
class FragmentC : DialogFragment() {

    //.....

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.DialogTheme
    
}
```

Also you need to change `C` in the navigation graph from a `fragment` to a `dialog`:

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="....">
</dialog>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want ***not to*** dismiss a dialog because it would stay on top of the next destination.

By "listen to result", if you mean `findNavController().currentBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.getLiveData(MY_KEY)`

then you should be able to set your result to `previousBackStackEntry` as it will give you the destination **before** your dialog.

```
Frag A : click on a button 
Frag A -> Dialog B : click on a button (automatically popped-off)
Frag A -> Dialog B -> Frag C : pop Frag C from the stack
```

then

```
class FragA : Fragment() {
    
    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        ...

        findNavController().currentBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<MyResult>(MY_KEY).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           // get your result here
           // show Dialog B again if you like ?
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class FragC : Fragment() {

    ...

    private fun setResultAndFinish(result: MyResult) {
        findNavController().apply { 
            previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(MY_KEY, result)
            popBackStack()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ianhanniballake made a good point why this is not entirely possible and why it works the way it works but there is actually a workaround. The workaround is not the most pleasant so keep this in mind. I've listed the drawbacks in it's own section below.

### The theory

The workaround involves some "older" Android mechanisms, mechanisms that predate navigation controller (we didn't always have navigation controller). The workaround revolves around a few facts:

1. All fragments live inside some `FragmentManager`. Navigation controller isn't magic, it still uses `FragmentManager`s under the hood. In fact you can think of Navigation controller as a wrapper around `FragmentManager`.
2. All fragments come with it's own little `FragmentManager`. You may access it via `childFragmentManager` within the fragment. Any fragments launched in `childFragmentManager` are considered that fragment's children.
3. When a fragment is moved to the "backstack", all of it's children move with it.
4. When a fragment is restored, so are it's children.

With these four facts we can formulate a workaround.

The idea is if we show all `DialogFragment`s on a fragment's `childFragmentManager` then we maintain the ability to navigate to other fragments without any dialog related issues. This is because when we navigate from say FragA to FragC, all of FragA's children is moved to the back stack. Since we launched the `DialogFragment` using `childFragmentManager`, the `DialogFragment` is automatically dismissed as well.

Now when the user moves back to our fragment (FragA), our `DialogFragment` is shown again because FragA's `childFragmentManager` is restored too. And our `DialogFragment` lives inside that `childFragmentManager`.

### The implementation

Now that we know how we will workaround this issue, let's start implementing it.

For simplicity, let's reuse the example you have given. That is we will assume we have fragments `FragA` and `FragC` and dialog `DialogB`.

The first thing is that as nice as Navigation component is, if we want to do this, we cannot use it to launch our dialog. If you use safe args, you can continue to reap it's benefits though since technically safe args isn't tied to Navigation component. Here's an example of launching Dialog B:

```kotlin
// inside FragA
fun onLaunchBClick() {
  val parentFragment = parentFragment ?: return
  
  DialogB()
    .apply {
        // we can still use safe args
        arguments = DialogBArgs(myArg1, myArg2).toBundle()
    }
    .show(parentFragment?.childFragmentManager, "DialogB")
}
```

Now we can have `DialogB` launch `FragC`, but there's a catch. Because we are using `childFragmentManager`, navigation controller doesn't actually see `DialogB`. This means that to the navigation controller, we are launching `FragC` from `FragA`. This can create an issue here if there are multiple edges to `DialogB` in the nav graph. The workaround to this is to make all of `DialogB`'s directions global. This is ultimately the downside to this workaround. In this case we can declare a global action to `FragC` and launch it via

```kotlin
// inside DialogB
fun onLaunchCClick() {
  val direction = NavMainDirections.actionGlobalFragC()
  findNavController().navigate(direction)
}
```

### The downsides

So there are some obvious downsides to this approach. The biggest one is all fragments the dialog can navigate to should be declared as global actions. The only outlier being if the dialog has exactly 1 edge. If the dialog only has a single edge and it is unlikely a new edge will ever be added, you can technically just add actions to it's only parent fragment instead.

As an example if `DialogC` can launch `FragmentC` and `FragmentD` and `DialogC` can be launched from `FragmentA` and `FragmentZ` (2 edges) then `DialogC` must use global actions to launch `FragmentC` or `FragmentD`.

The other downside is we can no longer use Navigation controller for launching dialog fragments that need to launch other non-dialog fragments. This downside is milder since we can at least still use safe args.

The final downside is that performance might be slightly worse. Consider an example where we have fragment `FragA` launch `DialogB` launch `FragC`. Now if the user taps back, `FragA` will be restored. But since `DialogB` is `FragA`'s child, `DialogB` will also be restored. This means that an extra fragment will need to be loaded and restored, reducing the performance of the back action. In practice this cost should be small as long as your fragment isn't saving a huge amount of state and as long as each fragment does not have too many children.